# Does the Android Complete Backup in debug functions is real "COMPLETE"?

Tags: backup

My android phone is going wonky since I washed its surface yesterday(Hey, where's my IP68?), cannot picking up any WIFI or 4G signals even I restart or go into safe mode(my SIM card and WIFI are good on other device). Now I'm trying to find a way to do the COMPLETE backup of my phone before I can do further actions like reset to factory default.

When I look into the debug mode, there is a "Complete backup to my PC" function got my eyes, and I'd like to know is it really COMPLETE? like I can back to my usual use immediately without re-enter my APPs login credentials after restoration?

Comment: there is no such option for complete backup. power down, open usb cover, the sim tray, remove cards and put device in oven at 50° degree celsius for several hours

Comment: Bringing @alecxs comment a step further: there's no **such thing** as a complete backup (unless the device is rooted or you have at least a custom recovery installed, supporting Nandroid backups). For details, please see: [How to fully backup non-rooted devices?](/q/28296/16575)

Comment: ouch, how sad even I know this is for the security, but the process of restoration always annoying

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3922213&page=13